# Java how to open url with command on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, url, command

I use the following to open a url in a browser on Windows :

```
Command="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE "+Url;

Process Child=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

What should I do to achieve the same on Mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `open`.

```
String Command="open "+"http://google.ca";
Process Child=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

Hope this helps